# почему перестает работать функция при повторном событии?

Tags: события

Пытаюсь сделать карусель. Сейчас работаю над функцией, которая при клике на индикаторе определяет индекс индикатора и меняет на картинку с соответствующим индексом. Функция срабатывает, но в дальнейшем, при клике на любой другой индикатор ничего не происходит. В т.ч. не удается отловить ошибку через инструменты разработчика.
В чем проблема?

```
let imageIndex = 0;

//array with photo
const picArr = [
  'golden-retriever-puppy.jpg',
  'Drathaar.jpg',
  "beagle.jpg",
  'alabay.jpg',
  'rizenshnautser.jpg',
  'Airedale.jpg',
];
showImage(imageIndex, pictureBlock);
function showImage(imageIndex, containerElement){
  containerElement.style.backgroundImage = "url(" +picArr[imageIndex]+ ")";
 //get list of indicators
  let indItems;
  const indicatorList = document.getElementById('indicatorList');
  if(indicatorList) {
    //delete list of indicators
    divIndicator.removeChild(indicatorList);
  } 
  //create new element with other picture
  indItems = document.createElement('ul');    
  divIndicator.appendChild(indItems);
  indItems.setAttribute('id', 'indicatorList');
  for (let i = 0; i < picArr.length; i++){
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    indItems.appendChild(item);
    item.setAttribute('data-order', i);
  }
  //change colour of running indicator item
  indItems.childNodes[imageIndex].setAttribute('id', 'start');
}
function defineIndicatorNumber(e){
  console.log(Number(e.target.getAttribute('data-order')));
  imageIndex = Number(e.target.getAttribute('data-order'));
  showImage(imageIndex, pictureBlock);
}

const indicatorButton = document.querySelectorAll('li');
indicatorButton.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', defineIndicatorNumber));
```

Спасибо за помощь, переписал цикл в котором происходит пересоздание следующим образом:

```
for (let i = 0; i < picArr.length; i++){
    item = document.createElement('li');
    indItems.appendChild(item);
    item.setAttribute('data-order', i);
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', defineIndicatorNumber));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы пересоздаете элементы `li`, а обработчик события `click` этим вновь созданным элементам не назначаете.

---

Стоп-стоп. Не надо на каждой итерации делать выборку всех `li`. А то Вы впадете в противоположный грех назначения многих одинаковых обработчиков одним и тем же элементам.

```
for (let i = 0; i < picArr.length; i++){
  item = document.createElement('li');
  indItems.appendChild(item);
  item.setAttribute('data-order', i);
  item.addEventListener('click', defineIndicatorNumber);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, Игорь! очень помог! теперь пересоздание выглядит так: 
for (let i = 0; i < picArr.length; i++){
    item = document.createElement('li');
    indItems.appendChild(item);
    item.setAttribute('data-order', i);
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', defineIndicatorNumber));
  }

Comment: ааа, понял. действительно, нужно к каждому созданному добавлять eventlistener, раз уж работает цикл.